# How do I tell if my drive has a BD/DVD/CD-Compatible optical pickup unit?

Tags: dvd, windows-server-2012, blu-ray

I'd like to import Ghost in the Shell: Arise from Japan.

I only have a DVD drive, but the disc is a Blu-Ray optical disc. However, I am told that this optical disk is "backwards compatible" with a [BD/DVD/CD compatible optical pickup unit](http://www.blu-ray.com/info/).

How can I check to see if my machine has a BD/DVD/CD compatible optical pickup unit?

[image]

Comment: I'd like to import [Ghost in the Shell: Arise from Japan](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%94%BB%E6%AE%BB%E6%A9%9F%E5%8B%95%E9%9A%8AARISE-GHOST-SHELL-ARISE-Blu-ray/dp/B00BB1MALO), but the disk is a Blu-Ray optical disk; however, I am told that this optical disk is "backwards compatible" with a [BD/DVD/CD compatible optical pickup unit](http://www.blu-ray.com/info/).

Comment: Just as an aside, how does one remove the activation watermark on the screen; the license is university issued, don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the title of the window states "TSSTCorp DVD+-RW" I believe it's a DVD/RW and not a Blu-Ray.  Check the logos on or near the bezel of the optical drive.

You should see BD in the name of the device in Device Manager if you have a Blu-Ray drive.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download a freeware tool called "[Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy)"

> Speccy is an advanced System Information tool for your PC. Need to find out what's inside your computer? No problem! Speccy will give you all the information you need.

[image]